# Is there a more efficient way of iterating over pixels from getImageData

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

I'm looping over all the pixels in an image, checking if a pixel is a certain colour then setting said pixel to yellow (r=250,g=250,b=250), else i'll set it to black (r=0,g=0,b=0).

You'll see the code to do the colour comparison below is a very primitive method, but it fits my use case just fine.

I'm currently just using a single for loop, see the code below.

```
var cavas = $("#canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    imageData = context.getImageData(),
    data = imageData.data; 

    var r, g, b, total;

    var MAX = SOME_CONST,
        MIN = SOME_OTHER_CONST;

for (var i = 0, max = data.length; i < max; i +=4) {

     r = data[i];
     g = data[i+1];
     b = data[i+2];
     total = r + g + b;

     if (total < MIN || total > MAX) {
         //This is the colour i'm after
         data[i] = 255;
         data[i+1] = 255;
         data[i+2] = 0;
     }
     else {
         data[i] = 0;
         data[i+1] = 0;
         data[i+2] = 0;
     }
}
```

Is there a more efficient method of performing this operation?

Comment: How do you get `colour`? Here you could maybe get some improvements by returning false as soon as possible, also see this [Mozilla Hacks Article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/). Ps: if you could clean up a little bit your code from typos, that would avoid people thinking you don't care about your question.

Comment: Edited. I need to check the entire image so I don't think returning false early is an option.

Comment: of course it is, to check an entire color, you need to check the 4 rgba values of each pixel. In your edited code (there are still typos btw ;-) ) you do the sum of the 3 rgb values. First, it won't be perfect (`#FF00FF` will be treated as `#0000FF`) and you access the 3 values (you don't seem to care about alpha). By changing your if block to `if(r===wantedR && b===wantedB && g===wantedG)`, you'll only check for the red pixel if it doesn't match. But still, have a look at this article I pointed out, it may be an option for you.

Comment: There are many ways to optimise this type of search, The optimisation are specific to the structure of the data. EG If the pixels you are looking for will also have at least 3 or more pixels adjoining also being the colour you are looking for you can, reduce the search image to 1/4 its size via nears neighbor. Then only check at full res when you find a pixels you want. Find something about the image and pixels you have that allow for refinement. If the pixels are randomly distributed from one image to the next, the search you have is the best you can do.